# Unable to boot Windows 10 from Bootcamp external HDD

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, windows, usb

I have installed `Windows 10 Pro` in `Mac OS X El Capitan` using Bootcamp, restored the same to external USB 3.0 HDD using `WinClone Pro`. Now I am getting error when booting to Windows.

[image]

**Steps followed:**

- Disabled SIP in Mac from recovery mode, using the command `csrutil disable` (this is requested by WinClone)
- Installed Windows in Mac using bootcamp, installed drivers
- Partitioned the external HDD
- Restored the bootcamp installation to external USB 3.0 HDD using WinClone Pro
- Removed the internal bootcamp installation using bootcamp
- Restarted to external bootcamp installation

I am using MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015).

Tried with F8 key, then safemode and it gives like the below:

[image]
[image]

[Reference Video](https://youtu.be/1SxA_OsPEgk)

Comment: What is the model year and screen size is your Mac? From the menu bar, select "About this Mac" to get the year/screen size. Do you know if Windows was installed in EFI or BIOS mode internally and externally?

Comment: When you copied Windows to the external drive, did you have Winclone build a new BCD file? This is an option you can set in the Preferences under Winclone.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I got that prompt and I said don't copy

Comment: @DavidAnderson I am using MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)

Comment: @DavidAnderson tried two times, one with creating new BCD file and next time without creating BCD file.

Comment: Have you viewed the sequel to your posted video: [How to Install Windows 10 Boot Camp External SSD USB 3.0 drive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9RHjVAQHb3E). Check out the screen shot at 1:28 into the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the Winclone product to install Windows on a external USB drive, it is extremely important that you first read all the instructions provided by Winclone.

Winclone provides the Web page: [Running Windows from an External Drive](https://twocanoes.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205025389-Considerations-for-Booting-Windows-from-an-External-Drive://). This page provides links to two videos. The [first link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1SxA_OsPEgk) is the same as given in your question. The [second link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9RHjVAQHb3E) provides the answer to your posted question.

Comment: I have tried the both scenarios in WinClone as you explained. Both the times windows works fine with internal bootcamp installation and it is not working when restored into external HDD.

Comment: The second and third screen-shots are continuous to the first one, which is generated after trying with F8 key as directed in the first pic.

Comment: Thanks, it worked after editing registry. Please update answer it will be helpful for others.

Comment: I have installed windows by allocating 30GB size and restored to 1TB HDD. Any idea how to use the remaining space in Windows?

Comment: I probably would not have allocated 1TB just for Windows. I would have partitioned the external disk for at least another hfs+ formatted partition. I would have installed OS X into this partition. This gives you a way to boot the computer if your internal disk becomes corrupted. Also, you can use the hfs+ formatted partition to backup the NTFS windows partition via Winclone.

Comment: @devo: Do you think my post about updating the BCD helped solve your problem? Or, was editing the registry the actual solution I should have posted?

Comment: Yes, updating BCD doesn't solve the problem. The registry have to be edited.